# Android Studio. No cached version of com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:26.1.2 available for offline mode

Tags: android, android-studio

Android Studio.

> No cached version of com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:26.1.2
>   available for offline mode.

1. Приложение компилируется, запускается и работает на телефоне нормально.
2. Build APK делает без ошибок.
   Но Generate Signed APK не хочет. Выдает указанную ошибку.
   Invalidate Cashes & Restart - делал.
   Rebuild Project - делал.
   Не помогает...

Еще сообщает:

> org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task
>   ':app:lintVitalRelease'.

P.S. Проблемы начались после обновления Android Studio до 3.1.2 (01.05.2018)

Comment: посмотрите тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49751066/failed-to-generate-apk-from-android-studio-3-1-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler to see if Command-line Options contains `--offline` https://stackoverflow.com/a/49586824/404597